# How to show multiline data on Vaadin Grid cell of a column

Tags: java, grid, vaadin, vaadin14

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfiJy.png)How to show multiline data in Vaadin Grid cell.

Tried out with \n with string but still showing in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the column, instead of using a `ValueProvider` that returns a string, you can use a `ComponentRenderer` and return a simple component where you can control the line break yourself

```
// linebreaks wont work like this
grid.addColumn(item -> "line1 \n line2");

// try this instead.
// or probable even better you could use the `Html` component from Vaadin
grid.addColumn(new ComponentRenderer<>(item -> {
    Span span1 = new Span("line1");
    Span span2 = new Span("line2");
    return new VerticalLayout(span1, span2);
}));
```

You can also use a TemplateRenderer, which will use less memory than a ComponentRenderer, but has a little steeper learning curve (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

```
grid.addComponentColumn(item -> {
    Span span1 = new Span("line1");
    Span span2 = new Span("line2");
    return new Div(span1, span2);
});
```

you can use this solution as well. both work fine.